# Delete spaces from items in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
input_list = ["1.2.3.4", " 2.3.4.5", "  3.4.5.6"]
```

And I'd like to remove that space in the second e third words... How can I do?

I tried with:

```
for x in input_list:
    x.strip(" ")
```

and with:

```
for x in input_list:
    x.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: You can't assign to literals. You didn't try these codes, don't you?

Comment: This is _too localised_ to ever be of use to a future reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_list = [element.strip() for element in your_list]
```

Comment: you did not test that.

Comment: @ChrisMueller edited.

Comment: You should also specify that the strip method without any arguments will remove all white spaces (including tabs and newlines). If you only want to remove regular spaces you should use `element.strip(' ')`